# QGIS 3.12 - Setting Project default CRS causes "Ballpark Transform"

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, error

I'm coming across an issue that I am unsure of whether it is a bug or the result of my error. My work data is all projected in NAD83 (CSRS) / MTM Zone 10. EPSG Code: 2952. [image: Default CRS]

I set QGIS to default to this projection. This was done on a blank/empty project ->Settings->Options->CRS->Set Default CRS. When loading QGIS (Empty project or not), I always get the following error:[image: QGIS ERROR]

At work where I use ArcMap, I haven't experienced this issue at all so am confused on how to address it nor what exactly is the cause.