# What is ballpark transform?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

What is a ballpark transform?

[image]

I read [QGIS 3.12 - Setting Project default CRS causes "Ballpark Transform"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364513/qgis-3-12-setting-project-default-crs-causes-ballpark-transform)
and
[QGIS warning ballpark transform from](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357269/qgis-warning-ballpark-transform-from)

but found the answers not really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Proj documentation https://proj.org/glossary.html?

> **Ballpark transformation**
>
> For a transformation between two geographic CRS, a ballpark
> transformation is a coordinate operation that only takes into account
> potential difference of axis orders (long-lat vs lat-long), units
> (degree vs grads) and prime meridian (Greewich vs Paris/Rome/other
> historic prime meridians). It does not attempt any datum shift, hence
> the “ballpark” qualifier in its name. Its accuracy is unknown, and
> could lead in some cases to errors of a few hundreds of metres.
>
> For a transformation between two vertical CRS or a vertical CRS and a
> geographic CRS, a ballpark transformation only takes into account
> potential different in units (e.g. metres vs feet). Its accuracy is
> unknown, and could lead in some cases to errors of a few tens of
> metres.
>
> **Note**
>
> The term “Ballpark transformation” is specific to PROJ.

Answer (score 7):

`Ballpark` is a rather informal term for `estimation`. QGIS warns you that the transformation probably will be off by a few `m` and that you should avoid relying on results gained from data transformed in such a way.

Comment: The term is sometimes used for lame jokes/comparison, like "That's not in the same ballpark, it's not even the same sport." But that's going off topic in this SE.

Comment: i think it's useful actually because the term comes from an idiom about baseball that may not be familiar to everyone: https://grammarist.com/idiom/in-the-ballpark-and-hit-one-out-of-the-ballpark/#:~:text=In%20the%20ballpark%20refers%20to,amount%2C%20but%20is%20near%20it.